# customising title of plots from loops in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, dplyr

I've created a loop to: 1) Generate percentage for each column based on `season` variable; and 2) Plot out the percentages into stacked bar plots.

I would like to do two things: 1) Instead of `df[[b]]` as the name for the first column of output `df_percent`, to have the actual column name that was looped; and 2) To label the x-axis of the plot with the column name it was looped over

This is the furthest I've gotten with my code:

```
colNames <- names(df)[-c(1,2,7,9,10,12,37,38,63,65,74,76,79,75,77,14,42,64,69,8,49,58,60,78)]
for(b in colNames){
  df_percent <- df %>% group_by(df[[b]]) %>% count(season) %>% mutate(Percent=n/sum(n)) %>% mutate(Percentage = round(Percent*100, digits=2)) %>% as.data.frame()
  print(df_percent)
  plt_pc <- ggplot(df_percent, aes(x=df_percent[,1], y=df_percent$Percentage, fill=df_percent$season)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(label=round(Percentage)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=3) + labs(y="Percentage (%)", title="Percentage Calculation", fill="season", x=df[[b]])
  print(plt_pc)
}
```

For `df_percent`, I've tried doing `names(df_percent) = "df[[b]]"` but that doesn't help to change the first column's name of `df_percent`. For the plot, `x=IPS[[b]]` gives a random value from the column that was looped and trying `x=paste0(colNames)` labels x-axis for all plots with the header for the first column that was looped over.

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know without a reproducible example, but I think this does what you want:

```
for(b in colNames){
  df_percent <- df %>% 
    group_by(!!!b) %>% 
    count(season) %>% 
    mutate(Percent=n/sum(n)) %>% 
    mutate(Percentage = round(Percent*100, digits=2)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
  print(df_percent)

  plt_pc <- ggplot(df_percent, aes(x=df_percent[,1], y=Percentage, fill=season)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=round(Percentage)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=3) + 
    labs(y="Percentage (%)", title="Percentage Calculation", fill="season", x=b)
  print(plt_pc)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sparrow for the solution! For `plt_pc` using `labs(x=b)` solved the x-axis labelling for the plots. For `df_percent`, using `group_by(!!!b)` does the job to keep the column name. I also tried `group_by(.data[[b]])` and that works too.

Comment: Cool. Consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  if it worked.